# Visual Studio 2012 Business Intelligence SSIS packages missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, ssis

I have Visual Studio 2012 solution with multiple BI projects. One of the SSIS projects do not show all the ssis packages in the Solution Explorer (checked in by another teammember). But the missing files are in the TFS (Source Control Explorer) and are visible in the physical folder.

I tried "Show all files" did not work. 
I tried adding the file again but the project does not allow that saying "file with same name exists".

Any idea what is going on here

Comment: Is it possible that the files were somehow excluded from the project?

Comment: If that's the case will it till get checked into TFS ?

Comment: The file will still exist inside of the project's files, it just won't be visible while inside the project. If you right click on any file, you'll see an 'Exclude from Project' option. This is what I believe happened.

Comment: When that happens to me, it's usually because I don't check in the project file along with the new/changed packages. Try checking out everything, add existing packages, and then check in all of them including the solution file.

Comment: The authoritative source of what's in a project is going to be the ProjectName.dtproj file. Inside of that will be entries for the packages that comprise the project. For a non-package deployment model, it's trivial to edit the file by hand and make your stuff show up. It's way too much effort to do that by hand for a 2012 project deployment model. Open the Project in Visual Studio (ssdt/bids) and right click on the project. Click Add Existing Item (not add package) and then click the "missing" package. Check your dtproj file in and all is right with the world.

Comment: Is it possible, that you have two project with the same name/assembly-name?

Comment: Billinkc - Your suggestion worked. "Add Existing Item" did the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The authoritative source of what's in a project is going to be the `ProjectName.dtproj` file.

Inside of that will be entries for the packages that comprise the project. For a non-package deployment model, it's trivial to edit the file by hand and make your stuff show up.

It's way too much effort to do that by hand for a 2012+ project deployment model. Open the Project in Visual Studio (ssdt/bids) and right click on the project. Click Add Existing Item (not add package) and then click the "missing" package. Check your .dtproj file in and all is right with the world.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in 2020, I managed to solve it by building the solution.

On the menu select Build-> Build Solution OR Ctrl+Shift+B